# remotely-built `java_binary`s can't run locally

Tags: bazel

I'm using Bazel 0.29.1 with remote execution to build `java_binary` targets.  They are straightforward targets with a few sources and deps, e.g.

```py
java_binary(
    name = "foo",
    main_class = "my.foo",
    runtime_deps = [
        "//my/foo",
        "//third_party/jvm/org/apache/logging/log4j:log4j_core",
    ],
)
```

The remote execution config is using `rbe_autoconfig` from Bazel toolchains 0.29.8 and the default build container.

The binary builds fine with `bazel --config=remote build //:foo`.  However, it fails when run with `bazel --config=remote run //:foo`:

```
/home/kgessner/.cache/bazel/_bazel_kgessner/[snip]/foo: line 359: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

The `java_binary` wrapper/launcher has the wrong java path: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java` is the path to java in the build container, but not locally.

I can't find the right combination of java flags to make this work: build remotely but use the local JRE when it's run.  What's the trick?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug. Could you please [file it on GitHub](http://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/new)?